# Why do I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver"?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, maven-3

I tried some of the advices given on other similar questions here, but failed to overcome the problem.
I am getting this error when trying to execute the jar by:

```
java -jar AutoHotRouter-1.0.jar
```

Given the following pom.xml, what am I missing here??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ttt</groupId>
    <artifactId>AutoHotRouter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>AutoHotRouter</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

First I added:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/libs
                </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.ttt.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I built the jar using

```
mvn clean install
```

then on

```
java -jar AutoHotRouter.jar
```

I got:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Then I removed the previous plugins and added firstly maven-assembly-plugin and because it didn't work for me, I replaced it with maven-shade-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.ttt.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation=
                                         "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.ttt.App</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

after

```
mvn clean install
```

and then

```
java -jar AutoHotRouter-1.0.jar
```

I get:

> no main manifest attribute

I also tried

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

with
maven-assembly-plugin.

Then I got:

> Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an assumption since the pom looks good so far. The part that's a bit suspicious is the jar plugin:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <configuration>
      ...
```

It looks like you later on try to execute the created jar file with `java -jar`? In that case all the dependencies you define in the pom will be missing. Either use the [dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) to collect the dependency jar files and use the classpath option when running the jar or use the [shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to create an uber-jar that will contain your classes as well as the dependencies.

Using your pom allowed me to start Chrome, so the dependencies look good. So I think the way you start it causes that exception.

Update: since you use this setup to automate chrome, the shade plugin seems the best way to go. I am able to start chrome with this pom and main class in src/main/java

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>HotRouter</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>HotRouter</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>org.example.StartMain</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Main-Class

```
package org.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class StartMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");

    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  }
}
```

Then `mvn package` and `java -jar ./target/HotRouter-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` opens chrome. Your config is almost the same (I think only the phase config for the shade plugin is missing)

Its important to have the shade plugin within the `<plugins>` section of the pom, as it is not part of [the default jar life-cycle](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging). The `<pluginManagement>` section is just there to configure defaults for versions and configuration. See [pom reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management). So additional plugins will not be automatically enabled if only in that section.

Comment: Thank you @wemu. I ADDED the shade plugin: <plugin><groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId><version>3.2.4</version><executions><execution><phase>package</phase><goals><goal>shade</goal></goals><configuration><artifactSet><excludes></excludes></artifactSet></configuration></execution></executions></plugin>. I still get the same error. Should I configure the plugin differently?

Comment: it all depends on how you run this build. your selenium dependencies don't have the test scope in pom.xml that would be common. The shade plugin is built to package your production sources into an executable jar. It will not include the test sources. So it depends where you placed your tests as well (usually src/test/maven but that is usually not included via the shade plugin). Does the maven build lead to the same exception? or are you actually trying to run this via the executable jar? That is also not very common for running tests.

Comment: Thanks @wemu. Acually I use Selenium only to automate Chrome and not for testing at all. Maven (mvn clean install) succeeds. java -jar aaa.jar gives the error...

Comment: I added more info to the question

Comment: did "mvn package" create the uber-jar? in the target folder there should be a bigger one and an "original-.jar" one. The shade plugin execution may also need the <phase>package</phase> near the goals section. You also don't need to configure the main class for the jar-plugin as the shade plugin will do that for the uber-jar.

Comment: I added <phase>package</phase> under the execution tag for the shade plugin. I removed the mainClass from the jar plugin settings. At the end, I left only the jar and the shade plugins from all the ones I tried above. The product is only one jar, with no mainClass entry in the manifest... :( wemu, I appreciate your help so much. Maybe we can continue privately (maybe by email), and when we'll solve it I'll be happy to accept your solution as an answer here?

Comment: well IK can't promise anything but if you have your project on github you could invite me there so I can have a look. I'm wemu on github as well.

Comment: sorry I get a 404 with that link. share settings for a repository are under settings, manage access. Probably https://github.com/dushkin/AutoHotRouter/settings/access

Comment: @dushkin ok. You where quite close. The pluginManagement section in the pom just declares your preferences for plugin versions and configuration. But if not a plugin that is part of the default lifecycle (see https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging) then you need to add that plugin into the plugins section as well (without version and configuration as you can have that in pluginManagement). Only whats inside plugins is enabled. As the shade plugin is not part of the jar packaging lifecycle that needed to be added there.

Comment: yes! yes! yes! Thank you wemu. If you will add an answer I will be happy to accept it!